# cookies and varnish- lots of headache

Tags: cookies, varnish

hi this is my varnish log for the main website page
    https://pastebin.com/RxsPKe7z

here is the hash things on my * vcl,it shows a good hit but why Im getting the hash returns?

-I have other pages that also sets WordPress logged in cookie for guests, i will share it on another question

- vcl recive

  ```
    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bz2|flac|flv|gz|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|ogm|opus|rar|tar|tgz|tbz|txz|wav|webm|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
  unset req.http.Cookie;
  return (hash); }


               if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|otf|ogg|ogm|opus|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
  unset req.http.Cookie;
  return (hash);
  ```

  }

  ```
  sub vcl_hash {
     # Called after vcl_recv to create a hash value for the request. 
    This is used as a key
    # to look up the object in Varnish.



    hash_data(req.url);

    if (req.http.host) {
      hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
      hash_data(server.ip);
    }



  #https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-cookies/
  if (req.http.cookie ~ "woocommerce_items_in_cart") {
  set req.http.X-TMP2 = regsub(req.http.cookie, ".*woocommerce_items_in_cart([^;]+);.*", "\1");
  hash_data(req.http.X-TMP2);
  unset req.http.X-TMP2;}

    if (req.http.cookie ~ "woocommerce_cart_hash") {
  set req.http.X-TMP3 = regsub(req.http.cookie, ".*woocommerce_cart([^;]+);.*", "\1");
  hash_data(req.http.X-TMP3);
  unset req.http.X-TMP3;}


   if (req.http.cookie ~ "woocommerce_session_") {
  set req.http.X-TMP4 = regsub(req.http.cookie, ".*woocommerce_session([^;]+);.*", "\1");
  hash_data(req.http.X-TMP4);
  unset req.http.X-TMP4;
   }



  return (lookup);
  }
  ```

I want to make sure that I'm on the right track

best.

Comment: this is one on my subpages https://pastebin.com/3vh3Rcsf  which shows HIT only on refresh for each session

Comment: You can use this guide (http://shakeelmuhammad.blogspot.com/2017/05/setup-varnish-4-and-w3-total-cache.html) to configure varnish for wordpress.